# I am facing an error in removing image button background

Tags: android, xml

**The error is:**

> error: '' is incompatible with attribute android:background (attr)
>   reference|color

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/report_btn"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/report_btn"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/service"
    android:layout_marginBottom="117dp"

    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/about_us"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/about"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/complaint_btn"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/achievement" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the background, why don't you delete this line?

```java
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

You should  not need to make a "transparent" color to remove the background in your `<ImageButton>`.

Comment: well i replaced "android:src="@drawable/about""  to "android:background="@drawable/about"" and it is working now.
thanks @akinoreiki